# Click on image to display larger version

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

This is related to earlier posts on [rescaling images after posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/rescaling-images-after-posting), but I'd like to propose a feature similar to Wikipedia.

There clicking on an image that appears in an article links to display of a larger version of the image (and supplementary information) if one is available.

In some cases Questions and Answers on Math.SE benefit from fairly detailed images, but displaying them at full size (by default) could or would break up the flow of text for Readers.

Optional use of "thumbnailed" sizes `l`,`m`,`s` appended to the filename in the image links embedded in posts allows detailed images to be uploaded but shown at reduced scale in the context of their posts.

Perhaps StackExchange already allows enough "embedded" HTML to implement something of this kind, but it would be a kindness IMHO to automate the function where the thumbnail feature has been used to give a reduced display size in a post.

**Added:**  I considered posting this to Meta.SE, but since my motivation is really for graphics as I use them here, I thought Meta.Math.SE was at least a good place to get feedback.

Comment: Large images are already reduced to fit the width of the post. For landscape-oriented images (most common ones), this has about the same effect as option `l` of imgur.  Options `m` and `s` result in poor image quality due to aggressive compression on imgur's part; I wouldn't recommend their use.  The status quo looks good enough to me: large images are shown reduced to width of post, and automatically linked to full-size version.

Answer (score 4):

After playing around with the "automatically linked" functionality that @404 mentions in the above Comment, I'll give a manual recipe for doing the linking to a full-sized image from a "thumb-nailed" size.

Long-time community members may have noticed [a change in the automatically generated image markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267508/what-happened-to-the-image-syntax), the [rationale for which](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259580/please-add-the-markdown-to-make-an-image-link-to-itself) is a long-standing Meta request closely related to mine, [Support showing image in original size in overlay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay).

To illustrate I'll use an image from Wikipedia that I converted (svg -> png) today for [a graph theory Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712135/can-anyone-find-a-k3-3-subdivision-on-the-petersen-graph).  Not so much because of the width, but rather for the vertical displacement, I think the medium `m` thumb-nail works best there.

The automatically generated markdown for the full sized image is then:

`[![enter text description][1]][1]`

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhWD.png`

Since we already (should) edit in a useful text description at the same time we modify the image link to append an `m`, it is only marginally more effort to make a second "outer" link to the full-sized image:

`[![Petersen subgraph as subdivision of forbidden K{3,3}][1]][2]`

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhWDm.png`

`[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhWD.png`

[image: Petersen subgraph as subdivision of forbidden K{3,3}]