# Is there any problem in my MathJax syntax?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Is there any MathJax error in my MathJax syntax?

Example: `\color{red} {\Large \displaystyle \mathcal {D}^{{\normalsize \left(\mathrm{III} \right)}}_n {\small \left( \dfrac{M}{N}\right)} :=Mn+N }`

$$\color{red} {\Large \displaystyle \mathcal {D}^{{\normalsize \left(\mathrm{III} \right)}}_n {\small \left( \dfrac{M}{N}\right)} :=Mn+N }$$

I'm having difficulty  [converting a formula](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php?filename=tempimagedir%2Feqn5464.png&latextext=%5Ccolor%7Bred%7D%20%7B%5CLarge%20%5Cdisplaystyle%20%5Cmathcal%20%7BD%7D%5E%7B%7B%5Cnormalsize%20%5Cleft%28%5Cmathrm%7BII%7D%20%5Cright%29%7D%7D_n%20%7B%5Ctiny%20%5Cleft%28%20%5Cdfrac%7BM%7D%7BN%7D%5Cright%29%7D%20%3A%3DMn%2BN%20%7D&outtype=png&bgcolor=white&txcolor=black&res=500&antialias=1) to a picture. I just want to know. Is there any problem in my MathJax code?

My goal is to actually write $\frac MN$ to a smaller size.

Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Why do you keep writing MathJAx? It should be MathJax. The syntax is that of $\rm\LaTeX$ anyway.

Comment: Your syntax is correct (not in error), but you might prefer `\tiny` to `\small` for your purpose.

Comment: I guess your problem lies in that third party website (to convert $\LaTeX$ to an image).  It doesn't seem to understand the font size qualifiers as `MathJax` does.

Comment: @hardmath If you want to send it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much..

Comment: I'll see if  there is a workaround and post that.

Comment: @hardmath thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [an alternative site](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) that converts $\LaTeX$ equations to images.  It documents the available commands much better than Roger's does (some of his links are 404).

In any case the command `\frac` can be replaced by `\tfrac`, producing a better vertical spacing that I think will satisfy you:

[image: image produced by Roger Cortesi site]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your answer is helpful for me because symbol `t` is works better. Actually my current equation is meaningles..This is just symbolic equation. real equation is too long. Therefore https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php does not support long equation..But Roger converts any long and complicated equation. In short your answer actually worked. I replaced `\tfrac`

Comment: But it can be possible completely different syntax instead of \small, \tiny, \large?

Comment: Apparently the site you used does not support those font size qualifiers.  I say apparently because the documentation links there are somewhat broken.  You could contact the site owner to ask about adding that support, but for a free service it might be asking too much.

Comment: Thank you very much. No need. :)

Comment: I hope no one is planning to post anything like *that* on main!

Comment: @GerryMyerson  ...This is  just a symbolic "equation"

Comment: Let me rephrase: I hope no one is planning to post anything in red in letters ten times normal size on main.

Comment: @hardmath, if it wasn't for the left and right on that fraction using _ on the numerator repeatedly, and ^ on the denominator you can make it go down in size. The parentheses don't follow suit though.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Sorry about the color scheme! But I did use the [click-thru trick](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22873/3111) to reduce the size of the generated image as displayed (click on it as a link to see the full size image).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the fraction smaller, you can write:

\tfrac M N

$$
\tfrac M N \quad \text{versus} \quad \frac M N
$$