# A specific confusing MathJax syntax that works randomly or not

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Today I ran into the specific MahJax problem for which I cannot find the cause.

Interestingly, if this Mathjax syntax somehow works in the Q&A area, it definitely doesn't work in the comment section. (I tried many times)

Now one more interesting problem than that is that the MathJax syntax I mentioned works "completely randomly" without my intervention, or it doesn't work.  The only thing I can do is refresh the page $10-15$ times.

As soon as the specific Mathjax syntax I mentioned runs, if the page is refreshed, unfortunately syntaxis won't work again.

Here is the MathJax syntax that "randomly works or doesn't work":

$$\cancel{\Longleftrightarrow}$$

Well here it didn't work either...

Here are the images I took:

[image]

[image]

What is the source of the problem?
I am not a computer user.

Comment: (Not an answer, but your post is a good example for [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/scaling-down-large-images-in-posts?cb=1) question.)

Comment: Not an answer but perhaps you are interested in `\nLeftrightarrow`$\nLeftrightarrow$ and `\nRightarrow`$\nRightarrow$

Comment: @CalvinKhor also $$\not\Longleftrightarrow$$ but seems not very good...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `$\require{cancel}$` to your post to be able to use it, `$\require{cancel}\cancel\Longleftrightarrow$` will produce $\require{cancel}\cancel\Longleftrightarrow$.

Comment: (+1)So how can you explain if it works randomly?with my syntax

Comment: It might loaded on some pages?

Comment: Important thing, we fixed the problem.  But I would like to know why this syntaxis is different.  Very interesting.

Comment: @lonestudent it's an extension of MathJax, not the basic package. In some circumstances it may still be available due to use elsewhere on the page (although my understanding is that the scope of MathJax extensions and definitions is *meant* to be limited to the applicable block).

Comment: I wonder whether the presence of `\require{cancel}` in one posting on a page can cause the `\cancel{}` command to work in other postings on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\niff{\iff\kern-1.75em/\kern1.25em}$
This method, using the `\cancel` macro from the package `cancel`, seems not to render the cancel stroke in the correct colour. Does that package always render the stroke in black? At any rate, it is practically invisible on a black background, and its only effect is to obliterate some of the symbol it is meant to be cancelling.

I instead suggest `\iff\kern-1.75em/\kern1.25em` within a MathJax expression. That bit of MathJax is rather bulky if you want to typeset that symbol more than once, so you could define a MathJax token for it, for example by `$\def\niff{\iff\kern-1.75em/\kern1.25em}$`. You may then write
`$P\niff Q$` for $P\niff Q$ or `$1\niff2$` for $1\niff2$.

(Earlier, in this question, I had based my definition of `\niff` on `\Longleftrightarrow` as that had already been mentioned in this question. But a comment by Calvin Khor to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33374) to [another question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33366) on a similar subject pointed out two advantages of `\iff` over `\Longleftrightarrow`: appropriate spacing and a name which suits what the symbol *means*. I accordingly use \iff.

Just as a check to see if the spacing looks right: the next line below uses `\iff` and the line below it uses my `\niff` defined above.

$\begin{gather}
P\iff Q\\ P\niff Q
\end{gather}$

Comment: Doesn't look very good to me. The slash should be in the middle of the arrow, but I'm seeing it way over at the left end instead.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see you're right -- trying it in TeX and magnifying x4 showed that I was about .05em off.

Comment: I'm still seeing it way over to the left.

Comment: What's a macro?

Answer (score 2):

Testing @MichaelHardy's [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/a-specific-confusing-mathjax-syntax-that-works-randomly-or-not#comment152031_33355) about whether `\require{cancel}` in one post enables it in others.  I assume it's present in @AsafKaragila's [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33355), since it uses the macro successfully, but I'm not sure how to view the source (I usually pretend to suggest an edit and then cancel it, but that doesn't work here).

PRE:  I assume that the answer is that "no, it doesn't", since the invocation in the parent post doesn't work.

$\cancel\Leftrightarrow$

POST:  Looks like I was wrong!  There's no `\require{cancel}` here, but it works.  So why *doesn't* it work in the parent post?

Comment: The order of how things are rendered may matter - Asaf's answer is displayed above yours because it is the accepted answer, which means the MathJax parser encounters `\require{cancel}` before the `\cancel` in your post. On the other hand, the parent post doesn't have a `\require{cancel}`. There have been similar issues in the past, but I thought they were solved by [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page) adjustment in 2019.